# How does one typeset accent marks outside of math mode?

Tags: support, markdown

My apologies for this very basic question.

> How does one typeset accent marks outside of LaTeX math mode?

For example, on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14499/highly-composite-number) both Derek Jennings and I cite papers from Paul Erdos.  Derek gets the double-dot accent mark on Erdos' name, but I don't know how.  When I pull up Derek's source there's no markdown there; just the symbol ö itself!  Of course, when I see an accented character that I want to use I can just copy it (which is what I just did with ö), but this doesn't help me if there's an accent mark I want to use but I haven't seen others use yet.

Another example: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez (copied from one of his posts).  I don't know how to get the acute accent mark on the a.

Comment: I cheat and use a "character map" program myself... :D

Comment: Erdős is spelt with an ő (U+0151 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DOUBLE ACUTE), not with a ö (U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS)!

Comment: By the way, this was discussed in http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/221/feature-request-adding-diacritics-in-markdown/

Comment: @Mariano: Thanks for the correction on Erdős.  I also hope you don't mind me using your name as an example. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using [Html Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). Which are usually of the form `&blah;` (ampersand, word, semi-colon).

Most common browsers should support them.

For example:

`&Otilde;`: Õ 
 
`&aelig;`:  æ 
`&agrave;`: à

If not, you can perhaps try using the [unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) itself and pasting it straight, like you did with ö.

Comment: Thanks, Moron.  This is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

One other way if you don't feel like memorizing HTML entity references is to [let someone else do the remembering for you](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/code/latexToUTF/utf.php).

[Edit: Live version of the script is dead; original author has placed the script [On GitHub](https://github.com/loopspace/latexToUTF), but you will need to have a way of serving up PHP scripts to run it.]

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks, Willie; I did not know such a thing existed.

Comment: I only found out from Andrew Stacey yesterday about his script. So neither did I until 30 hours ago.

Comment: Seems the link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do cut-n-paste. I get most of those characters from tables such as [this one from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso-8859-1).

I mention this because it seems that HTML character reference does not work in comments; typing `pr&eacute;simplifiable` in the body will produce "présimplifiable", but in the comments you'll get the literal text. See for example my last comment in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14275/associates-in-the-ring-of-polynomials-mod-n/14330#14330) (if you were wondering why I chose that word just now...).

Comment: Or just check here with pr&eacute;simplifiable.